# Authenticating to Hashicorp Consul from a VM

Tags: azure, authentication, automation, consul

I am trying to understand how can I authenticate to Consul from a VM. I have Azure AD as IDP, but it's not clear from the documentation whether it can be used to retrieve JWT token to use it later to access Consul.

Can someone please advice?